# Items on my Developer Story are appearing out of order

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

My Developer Story [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/story/thomasjowens).

My current position (Software Engineer at DrugDev) is listed at the top. I expect the line to be a timeline showing things in a reverse chronological order. However, recent certifications are displayed below the most recent position. Likewise, some certifications are out of order. my IEEE Certified Software Development Associate certificate (earned in December 2010) is listed higher than the job that I started in July 2011. The PluralSight IQ assessment that I took in February 2018 is listed between the IEEE certification and the job I started in July 2011.

The placement of these things feel weird. And if it feels weird and confusing to me, I'm sure it may feel weird and confusing to anyone else looking at this format. Not only is it different than a resume or CV style, but the ordering doesn't make much sense.

---

Based on the answer, it seems like this may be intended behavior. However, since it's confusing to me, I suspect that it may also be confusing to people who read a Developer Story - recruiters, hiring managers, and people who just want to learn about someone's background. I'd argue that the confusing presentation is a user experience defect.

Sorting by end date may make sense for some things, the start or effective date may make more sense for other things. I'd argue that the start date (or creation date or release date) is important for blogs/videos, posts, features/apps, certification, assessment, and milestone. The end date is more important for positions, open source projects, and education.

---

This is still a problem and has been tagged as status-review since September 2018 - that's over 20 months. I'd like to see this get planned or declined soon.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The current behavior is by design so I've tagged this as a feature request and set it to status-review as the team will be looking at improvements to Developer Story over the next few months.

Comment: This behavior also occurs for publications, where it is a bit more insidious since the only field is the start date. On my story I have several events that started in 2015, but my 2019 publication appears *after* all of them due to the start date. At a minimum it seems like the story should be clamped to ensure that single date events appear correctly.

Answer (score 3):

All entries are sorted by *end date*, then by start date.

Everything at the top is still 'current' (without an end date), so they are all listed first, sorted in reverse chronological order. Only then do items with an end date set come in.

The solution is to give all those items an end date.

Comment: From my perspective, that's awful. I'm not going to give something and end date that doesn't have one (they don't even have future end dates). This order is very confusing to me, and probably to recruiters or hiring managers or just people reading it to understand my history as well.

Comment: @ThomasOwens: I agree on that point. I never show the story view to anyone, it's always the CV view that I hand out (either as a PDF or a link).

Comment: The story view is really cool. But I may stop linking to it for this very reason. I still consider this a bug.

Answer (score -4):

Sorry, we still don't have any plans to change this behaviour. I've updated it to status-declined.

Comment: Would [tag:status-deferred] be more appropriate? But I would like to say that since I posted this, my Developer Story has been made even less useful due to this ordering. It's unfortunate that a resolution to an issue that degrades the functionality so much isn't being planned.

Comment: @ThomasOwens Same here, the Developer Story lost all usefulness as a result of this UI/UX decision.

Comment: It is totally useless.. no scratch that, it is worse than useless. It just causes confusion.